# PopupView.showAtLocation is undefined for the type View

Tags: android, view, contextmenu, undefined, popupwindow

I am working on an app in which I display a `ContextMenu`. Now, when one of the menu items in this `ContextMenu` is pressed, I would like to display a `PopupWindow`. I have found some examples of how to use `PopupWindow` on the internet but I still have a problem. I have the following code:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
popupView.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.main_layout), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

And in the Activity's XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#232323" >

....

</RelativeLayout>
```

I thought this should work, but I get the following error message:

**"The method showAtLocation(View, int, int, int) is undefined for the type View"**

What does this mean? I am giving showAtLocation a View and three integers, right? So what's the problem? Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling it with popView.
instead you should call it with popupWindow.

this method is for popupwindow not for view

Comment: Wow thanks for the fast response! Stupid that I didn't see that myself :) .

Answer (score 2):

```
popupView.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.main_layout), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

change this line to

```
popupWindaow.showAtLocation(popupView,Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

like this.

Note that. You have set `showAtLocation` for  `Windaow`, not for `View`

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

popupview.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

first param view is a View in your current page, based on that view position this popup view is  appear